# Parsing JSON returns NULL iOS

Tags: php, iphone, json, null

I'm trying to parse the JSON string:

```
array(3) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["source"]=>
  string(12) "setWorldTime"
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

With this code:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    // Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/con.php?m=setWorldTime&a=London,0"]];

    // Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    // Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(json_string);
    // parse the JSON response into an object
    // Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
    NSDictionary *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    NSLog(@"OK: %@", [[statuses objectForKey:@"array"] objectForKey:@"result"]);
```

But instead of output 'OK: success' it outputs 'OK: (null)'
If you need the PHP script I can post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string you have is anything but JSON... looks like `var_dump()` or something from PHP.  That's why it can't be parsed.

You need to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on your PHP end instead.

Comment: @TheDeveloper, I doubt any API outputs that intentionally.  Looks like someone's debugging code to me.

Comment: @TheDeveloper, Is this your PHP script serving the data?  If so, yes, rather than `var_dump()`, use `json_encode()`.  If this is someone else's, tell them to output in some standard data format.  I suppose you could write a parser for `var_dump()`'s output, but why would you want to?

Comment: Why are you not using an Json lib for iOS?

Comment: So after using `json_encode` it outputs as `string(59) "{"result":"success","source":"setWorldTime","success":true}"`

Comment: @TheDeveloper, Stop using `var_dump()` and just output the string.  If that string is in your log on the iOS side, then yes, you are now doing it correctly.

Comment: `{"result":"success","source":"setWorldTime","success":true}` is valid now I just need Objective-C to work...

Comment: Never mind, fixed it myself! Accepting answer.. In 4 minutes -_-.